# Explaining corr2 function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation

Can someone explain to me the correlation function `corr2` in MATLAB? I know that it is for 2D comparing similarities of objects, but in the equation [image] I have doubts what it is `A` and `B` (probably matrices for comparison), and also `Amn` and `Bmn`.

I'm not sure how MATLAB executes this function, because I have found in several cases that the correlation is not executed for the entire image (matrix) but instead it divides the image into blocks and then compares blocks of one picture with blocks of another picture.

In MATLAB's documentation, the `corr2` equation is not put as referral point to the way the equation itself is calculated, like in other functions in MATLAB's documentation, such as referring to what book it is taken from and where it is explained.

Comment: You can type 'edit corr2' in MAtlab's command line, and check its implementation. MAtlab's documentation of corr2 with formulas is here http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correlation coefficient is a number representing the similarity between 2 images in relation with their respective **pixel intensity**.

As you pointed out this function is used to calculate this coefficient:

[image]

Here A and B are the images you are comparing, whereas the subscript indices m and n refer to the **pixel location** in the image. Basically what Matab does is to compute, for every pixel location in both images, the difference between the intensity value at that pixel and the mean intensity of the whole image, denoted as a letter with a straightline over it.

As Kostya pointed out, typing `edit corr2` in the command window will show you the code used by Matlab to compute the correlation coefficient. The formula is basically this:

```
a = a - mean2(a);
b = b - mean2(b);
r = sum(sum(a.*b))/sqrt(sum(sum(a.*a))*sum(sum(b.*b)));
```

where:
a is the input image and b is the image you wish to compare to a.

If we break down the formula, we see that `a - mean2(a)` and `b-mean2(b)` are the elements in the numerator of the above equation. `mean2(a)` is equivalent to `mean(mean(a))` or `mean(a(:))`, that is the mean intensity of the whole image. This is only calculated once.

The 3rd line of code calculates the coefficient. Here `sum(sum(a.*b))` calculates the double-sum present in the formula element-wise, that is considering each pixel location separately. Be aware that using `sum(a)` calculates the sum in every column individually, hence in order to get a single value you need to apply `sum` twice.

That's pretty much the same happening in the denominator, however calculations are performed on `a-mean2(a)^2` and `b-mean2(b)^2`. You can see this a some kind of normalization process in which you consider the pixel intensity difference among each individual image.

As for your last comment, you can break down an image into small blocks and calculate the correlation coefficient on them; that might save some time for very large images but since everything is vectorized the calculation is quite fast. It might be useful in distributed processing I guess. Of course the correlation coefficient between 2 blocks of images is not necessarily identical to that of the whole image.

For the sake of curiosity you can look at [this](http://jps.anl.gov/vol.2/3-Correlation.pdf) paper which highlights some caveats in using the correlation coefficient for image comparison.

Hope that makes things a bit clearer!

Comment: Ty very much, it was much helpful.

Comment: you're welcome! If you found it helpful please mark it as accepted (green checkmark on the side) so the thread is closed; Thanks!

Comment: The link of the paper is broken. Could you correct it